# Conditional Random Field (CRF) implementation / library

Tags: c++, crf, markov-random-fields

I am looking for a free C++ conditional random field (CRF) implementation but not for text processing.

There are bunch of cool implementations:

- **CRFsuite**  (for text processing)
- **CRF++**     (for text processing)
- **JGMT**      (Matlab - MEX   not C++)

There are other packages like   **Darwin**   and   **HCRF**   with no usage examples in C++.

I'm wondering if anybody know any C++ CRF library other than what I mentioned above or know any example on how to setup and use Darwin or HCRF?

Comment: [See point 4. please](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: CRFsuite works fine for non-text things (but all it gives you is linear-chain CRFs)

Comment: Nowadays there is an implementation that use DGM and OpenCV:
https://github.com/ereator/Dense-CRF

Answer (score 1):

[DenseCRF](https://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/densecrf/) is a great library that performs dense conditional random field (fully-connected CRF) very efficiently. The package comes with an easy to understand C++ demo and some examples. It is very fast and produces promising results on image data.

Answer (score 1):

[DGM](http://research.project-10.de/dgm) is a very poserful but simple-to use CRF library, written on C++11. It was designed especially for image processing and includes many usage examples in tutorials.

It also includes the DenseCRF, mentioned in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is DGM C++ library implementing CRFs for image classification: http://research.project-10.de/dgm